# Http GET/POST request in Coccos2d-X

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am new to using `Cococs2d-X` for game development. I am trying to find some example of using the `HttpClient` library in my game. Can anyone show me an example ?

Comment: is it really so hard to check cocos2d-x documentation on their website? http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_use_CCHttpClient

Comment: It's hard when the code on the site doesn't compile and you don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 9):

For Cocos-2dx 3.3, you need to include the following headers and declare using the namespaces:

```
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "network/HttpClient.h"

USING_NS_CC;
using namespace network;
```

Then you can create the HttpRequest directly:

```
HttpRequest* request = new HttpRequest();
request->setRequestType(HttpRequest::Type::GET);
request->setUrl("http://YOUR_URL");
request->setResponseCallback(CC_CALLBACK_2(HttpClientTest::onHttpRequestCompleted, this));
request->setTag("Get test");
HttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);

request->release();
```

Your callback function could handle the response:

```
void HttpClientTest::onHttpRequestCompleted(HttpClient *sender, HttpResponse *response) {
    if (response && response->getResponseCode() == 200 && response->getResponseData()) {
        vector<char> *data = response->getResponseData();
        string ret(&(data->front()), data->size());
        CCLOG("%s", ("Response message: " + ret).c_str());
    }
    else {
        CCLOG("%s", ("Error " + to_string(response->getResponseCode()) + " in request").c_str()); //error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a basic code for hitting a url with getPost method

```
cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest *request=new cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest();

request->setUrl("your url");
request->setRequestType(cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest::kHttpPost);
request->setResponseCallback(this, httpresponse_selector(LoadingScene::yourCallBackMethod));

CCString *data = CCString::createWithFormat ("%s",yourData);

request->setRequestData(data->getCString(), data->length());
extension::CCHttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);
```

you define yourCallBackMethod like this...

```
yourCallBackMethod(cocos2d::extension::CCHttpClient *sender,cocos2d::extension::CCHttpResponse *response){

        std::vector<char> *buffer = response->getResponseData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is based on Test of cocos2d-x

// test 1

```
        CCHttpRequest* request = new CCHttpRequest();
        request->setUrl("http://just-make-this-request-failed.com");
        request->setRequestType(CCHttpRequest::kHttpGet);
        request->setResponseCallback(this, httpresponse_selector(HttpClientTest::onHttpRequestCompleted));
        request->setTag("GET test1");
        CCHttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);
        request->release();



 /*******************************************************************************/  

    void HttpClientTest::onHttpRequestCompleted(CCHttpClient *sender, CCHttpResponse *response)
{
    if (!response)
    {
        return;
    }

    // You can get original request type from: response->request->reqType
    if (0 != strlen(response->getHttpRequest()->getTag())) 
    {
        CCLog("%s completed", response->getHttpRequest()->getTag());
    }

    int statusCode = response->getResponseCode()

    if (!response->isSucceed()) 
    {
        CCLog("response failed");
        CCLog("error buffer: %s", response->getErrorBuffer());
        return;
    }

    // dump data
    std::vector<char> *buffer = response->getResponseData();
    printf("Http Test, dump data: ");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < buffer->size(); i++)
    {
        printf("%c", (*buffer)[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Errors "Use of undeclared identifier CCHttpClient".  Suggests I change to cocos2d::network::HttpClient, which errors "Incomplete type cocos2d::network::HttpClient named in nested name specifier".